# What is the best way in ruby to find if all the elements of one array are also present or not in the other array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following two arrays

```
a= [1,2,3,4]
b= [1,2]
c= [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want a method which return boolean value something like following

```
a.<some_method>(b) #should return true 
b.<some_method>(c) #should return false
```

suppose i use `include?` it will not work as it is expecting b as an element in the other array

currently i am doing something like following

```
b.all?{|x| a.include?(x) }
```

I want to know is there any better/fast way as my both the arrays having large lengths

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just check the result of second array subtracted from first array.

In your case B - A will be empty, but C - A will be non-empty...

Comment: this approach gives inconsistent result if there are duplicate entries in one of these arrays.

Answer (score 6):

In the simplest case the array operations are good.

But for extensive cases I think you need set operations. You can have a look at **http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html**.

Like in your case, it should be

```
a= [1,2,3,4].to_set
b= [1,2].to_set
c= [1,2,3,4,5].to_set

a.superset?(b)   # -> true
b.superset?(c)   # -> false
```

Comment: This is a really good option if (and only if) the arrays contain no duplicates. If you wanted to see if `[1, 2, 3]` contains `[2, 2]` this wouldn't work.

Comment: If `a = [1, 2, 3].to_set` and `b = [2, 2].to_set` then `a.superset?(b) ` returns `true`. The array subtraction `[1, 2, 3]- [2, 2]` also returns empty. Am i missing any other scenario?

Comment: Yeah, it returns true, but `a` doesn't strictly contain `b` (it doesn't have two `2`s). Rereading the OP I don't think that's actually a problem in this case.

Answer (score 4):

array & other_array returns the matching elements between array and other array and removes any duplicates.  You can create a boolean test to see if all elements of one array are in another by comparing the unique elements of the one array to the intersecting elements of the two combined arrays.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5]
c = [4,5,6,7]

# check if all items in one array are in another array

def all_items_in_array?(original_array, test_array)
    test_array.uniq == original_array & test_array
end
```

This method will return a boolean value

```
all_items_in_array?(a,b) # true
all_items_in_array?(a,c) # false
all_items_in_array?(b,c) # false
```

and for a boolean check with dupilcations

```
def all_items_including_duplicates_in_array?(original_array, test_array)
    original_grouped = original_array.group_by{|item| item}.values
    test_grouped = test_array.group_by{|item| item}.values
    test_grouped == original_grouped & test_grouped
end
```

Comment: You should consider adding some explanations (text + references) to improve the quality of your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both the array difference and Set#subset? answers are nice, but OP asked specifically about speed.  The best way to answer performance questions is to actually time the different approaches. [Benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to the rescue:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

BIG = 10_000
N = 1_000_000
SLOW_N = 500

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2]
c = [1,2,3,4,5]

bigA = (1..BIG).to_a
bigB = bigA.dup
bigB.pop
bigC = bigA.dup << (BIG+1)

setA = a.to_set
setB = b.to_set
setC = c.to_set
bigsetA = bigA.to_set
bigsetB = bigB.to_set
bigsetC = bigC.to_set

puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION
Benchmark.bm(21) do |x|
  x.report('Array#-')     { N.times{ (b-a).empty?; (c-a).empty? } }
  x.report('Set#subset?') { N.times{ setB.subset?(setA); setC.subset?(setA) } }
  x.report('big Array#-')     { SLOW_N.times{ (bigB-bigA).empty?; (bigC-bigA).empty? } }
  x.report('big Set#subset?') { SLOW_N.times{ bigsetB.subset?(bigsetA); bigsetC.subset?(bigsetA) } }
  x.report('big all? Set#include?')  { SLOW_N.times{ bigB.all?{|x| bigsetA.include?(x)}; bigC.all?{|x| bigsetA.include?(x)} } }
end
```

Results show that for small sets there's no significant difference. For large ones `Set#subset?` is about 20% faster:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]
                            user     system      total        real
Array#-                 1.520000   0.000000   1.520000 (  1.518501)
Set#subset?             1.520000   0.000000   1.520000 (  1.533306)
big Array#-             2.180000   0.000000   2.180000 (  2.180390)
big Set#subset?         1.720000   0.000000   1.720000 (  1.724991)
big all? Set#include?   2.130000   0.000000   2.130000 (  2.142015)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [a, b, c]
arr.reduce(:&)
```

will get you the consistent elements

I am after the inconsistent ones as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]
c = [2,3,4]

(a & b).any? or (a & b & c).any?
```

Comment: Except... you can't. This only tests if *some* of the elements of `b` are present in `a` (or in the latter case, in all three arrays). The question is how to test if *all* of the elements of `b` are in `a`.